# Why my savedInstanceState is not working?

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, android-lifecycle

I'm new to android studio with kotlin.

I want to make multiple choice quiz app, and I use data class and object constant to supply problem.  If users choose correct choice, private var mCurrentPosition(Int) get plus 1 and setQuestion() work to change the problem, choices, and correctChoice.

To prevent the progress from being reset after the app is closed, I thought it would be okay if the int of mCurrentPosition was stored, so I use onSaveIntanceState. But progress is initialized after the app is closed...

```
class QuizActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var mCurrentPosition: Int = 1
    private var mQuestion300List: ArrayList<Question300>? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            with(savedInstanceState) {
                mCurrentPosition = getInt(STATE_SCORE)
            }
        } else {
            mCurrentPosition = 1
        }
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz)


        val questionList = Constant.getQuestions()
        Log.i("Question Size", "${questionList.size}")

        mQuestion300List = Constant.getQuestions()

        setQuestion()

        tv_choice1.setOnClickListener {
            if (tv_correctChoice.text.toString() == "1") {
                mCurrentPosition ++
                setQuestion()
            } else {
                tv_choice1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_wrongchoice)
            }
        }
        tv_choice2.setOnClickListener {
            if (tv_correctChoice.text.toString() == "2") {
                mCurrentPosition ++
                setQuestion()
            } else {
                tv_choice2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_wrongchoice)
            }
        }
        tv_choice3.setOnClickListener {
            if (tv_correctChoice.text.toString() == "3") {
                mCurrentPosition ++
                setQuestion()
            } else {
                tv_choice3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_wrongchoice)
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        outState?.run {
            putInt(STATE_SCORE, mCurrentPosition)
        }
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)
    }

    companion object {
        val STATE_SCORE = "score"
    }

    private fun setQuestion() {
        val question300 = mQuestion300List!![mCurrentPosition-1]
        tv_question.text = question300!!.question
        tv_choice1.text = question300.choice1
        tv_choice2.text = question300.choice2
        tv_choice3.text = question300.choice3
        tv_correctChoice.text = question300.correctChoice
        tv_now.setText("${mCurrentPosition}")

        tv_choice1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_problem)
        tv_choice2.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_problem)
        tv_choice3.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape_problem)
    }
}
```

here is my app code. plz give me help :) thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`savedInstanceState` is really only meant for two things

- surviving rotations, where the `Activity` gets destroyed and recreated
- the system killing your app in the background - so when you return, the `Activity` needs to be recreated as it was, so the user doesn't see any difference between the app just being in the background, and the app being killed to save resources

When `onCreate` runs, if the `Activity` is being recreated from a previous state, you'll get a bundle passed in as `savedInstanceState` - this contains all the stuff you added in `onSaveInstanceState` before the app was stopped earlier. **But if the user has closed the app** (either by backing out with the back button, or swiping the app away in the task switcher etc.) then that's counted as a **fresh start** with **no state** to restore. And `savedInstanceState` will be null in `onCreate` (which is one way you can check if it's a fresh start or not).

So if you want to persist state even after the app is explicitly closed by the user, you'll need to use something else. [Here's the docs on the subject](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/saving-states) - the typical way is to use `SharedPreferences` for small data, some kind of database like Room for larger state. [`DataStore`](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore?hl=en) is the new thing if you wanted to try that out